# Understanding Razor data persistance

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am currently learning about razor pages and I got stuck with this matter:

- I have a custom class which contains a cluster of members, including
  arrays of other custom classes.
- They are initiated once the page starts. After that, the user may
  change values or add or delete array rows.
- However, once the user confirms the changes, OnPost throws an
  exception as if the arrays had never been initiated.

What is the best way to solve this?

*Code sample:*

```
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public long UID { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int UDEP { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public int nExpenses { get; set; }

    // Custom object
    [BindProperty]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Employee = new Employee(UID, UDEP);

        // Loading arrays data from a Database
        Employee = Employee.ExtractPersonalData(UID);
        Employee.Expenses.ExtractSheet(Month, Year, Employee.ID);
        Employee.Expenses.ExtractBoard();
        Employee.Expenses.ExtractProjects(Month, Employee.ID);
            // There are 1 boards and 4 projects with 30 decimal[] each

        nExpenses = Employee.Expenses.Boards.Count > 0 ? Employee.Expenses.Boards[0].Projects.Count : 0;
    }


    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        // All variables within Employee equal NULL
        if(nExpenses < Employee.Expenses.Boards[0].Projects.Count)
            DeleteRow();
        else if (nExpenses > Employee.Expenses.Boards[0].Projects.Count)
            AddRows();

        Employee.Expenses.SaveSheet();
    }
```

Comment: `Get` and `Post` are different actions, unless your posting all your Get data back, you wont have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep data passed by OnGet method in view (like `hidden controls`), then pass them to OnPost method, and OnPost method need to `receive parameter` from view to get the data in OnGet method.

I created a simple demo for your reference:

```
  [BindProperty]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Employee = new Employee()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "aaaa"
        };
        nExpenses = 1;
    }


    public void OnPost(Employee employee)
    {
    }
```

View:

```
@page
@model WebApplication_core_razorpage.Pages.CodeSampleModel
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
<form method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employee.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employee.Name)
    <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="button" />
</form>
```

Employee class:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the debug process:

[image]

Comment: This solved it. Thank you a lot for the demo sample.